# Apply changes for disable\enable proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, batch-file, cmd.exe

I copyed\pasted and compiled from posts of internet the new batch-file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('ipconfig ^| find "192.168.122.1"') do set VAR=%%i
if %VAR:~33% EQU 192.168.122.1 (
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
echo Proxy Enabled
) else (reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
echo Proxy Disabled)
```

The batch-file working good. But need open proxy settings(example ie) to apply the changes. How to apply it from cmd without open settings???